# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceException

Tags: java, mdx, pentaho, olap, olap4j

I'm trying to create a report from an olap4j datasource

```
DriverConnectionProvider provider = new DriverConnectionProvider();
provider.setDriver("mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver");
provider.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/FoodMart1");
provider.setProperty("Catalog", "C:/Users/mimi/Documents/FoodMart.xml");
provider.setProperty("JdbcUser","postgres" );
provider.setProperty("JdbcPassword", "*****");
provider.setProperty("JdbcDrivers", "org.postgresql.Driver");        
BandedMDXDataFactory factory = new BandedMDXDataFactory(provider);
factory.setQuery("MyQuery",query.getMdxQuery() );
MasterReport report = new MasterReport();
report.addPreProcessor(new RelationalAutoGeneratorPreProcessor());
report.setDataFactory(factory);
```

But I'm having this problem at the line MasterReport report = new MasterReport() :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a JAR file on your classpath, which from a bit of googling turns out to be [libloader](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlibloaderjar.htm).

If you /do/ have it on your classpath, you probably have the wrong version